# How to alter values in a class from within a function?

Tags: python

```
class Rock:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
    def move(length):
        length = length + 1


rock1 = Rock(100,300)
rock2 = Rock(300,500)
rocklist = [rock1,rock2]
gameover = 1
counter = 0
while gameover == 1:
    for i in rocklist:
        move(i.length)
        print(length)
```

When running this, `length` remains the same, as demonstrated by the `print`. How can I change the values using a function?

Comment: You're not trying to alter the values from a function. You're also printing `length`, not `i.length`, which should be causing a `NameError` since it's undefined at that point.

Answer (score 3):

There is an object `self` for all object methods that references to object itself:

```py
def move(self, movement_amount):
    self.length += movement_amount
```

You can call object methods from the object itself:

```py
rock1 = Rock(100,300)
rock1.move(1)  # Increase the length of this object by 1
```

In your case:

```py
while gameover == 1:
    for rock in rocklist:
        rock.move(1)
        print(rock.length)
```

Comment: You may also want to note how to call methods as well, since they are doing `move(rock.length)` instead of `rock.move(length)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create move function as a class function and then use it on the each rock object. This is how code structure will look like:

```
class Rock:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def move(self):
        self.length = self.length + 1

rock1 = Rock(100,300)
rock2 = Rock(300,500)
rocklist = [rock1,rock2]
gameover = 1
counter = 0
while gameover == 1:
    for rock in rocklist:
        rock.move()
        print(rock.length)
```